# Why doesn't java use a keyword like 'Typedef' in Cpp

Tags: java, c++

In my understanding, the keyword `typedef` is used to create a alias for a specific primitive type.

e.g.
  [image: The C++ Example Code]

Moreover, to distinguish between two objects with the same class name by emphasising the different package names in Java.

e.g.

```
com.aic.jon.Car car = new Car();
  com.aic.chupengyu.Car car = new Car();
```

However, it's too complicated compared to C++. We could use 'typedef' to solve this problem with fewer codes than Java. And with the keyword 'extends' in java, we could also create diffrent objects extending the same superclass, but why doesn't Java adopt the keyword 'typedef'? It seems to be more simpler and flexible to use typedef in java.

Comment: Because Java has platform independent primitive types.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ. Somehow I was able to post an answer after you closed the question. Magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides act as a convenience, `typedef` provides a way of making code cross-platform. The primitive types in C++ are platform dependent. However, most platforms/compilers will provide definitions of standard headers that define platform-independent types, like `uint32_t`, and quasi-independent types like `size_t`. Different machines will have different `typedef`s to make this work, but the end result is that code which relies on them can be ported much more easily.

Java already has a platform-independent definition for all it's primitive types, so there is no real need for anything equivalent to `typedef`.

Comment: Thank you very much. So the reason is the feature of good cross-platform  in java.

Comment: That's one way to put it. The mechanism in C++ is there to satisfy a need, and Java satisfies the need in other ways.

Comment: `typedef` serves multiple needs.  Making code cross-platform is just one of them.

Comment: @mernst. Agreed. But most of the other uses are to some extent sugar.